# Structure a complex typescript project with multiple, separate projects

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, build, module, lerna

I'm working on a complex project and we're using typescript. To date, the team has mostly built fairly monolithic projects but we have need to create some base libraries that will be used by this 'project' and people who take a dependency on our project. These libraries should be reusable modules. We're not ready to publish to NPM (yet, won't be for a while). I can't find much guidance on how to structure these projects.

We're using vscode and are playing with lerna, so we have.

```
/root (we open this in VSCode)
   /packages
       /package-1
       /package-2
       /package-3
```

Where package-1 might be the reusable library (that one day might live on NPM). Both package-2 and package-3 will take a dependency on the package-1 library. We're working on all three at the same time so having them in the same workspace and build is great.

What's the best way to reference these projects? I don't want to have mangled code that has an import statement like this

`import {foo} from '../package-1/dist/package-1'`

And would rather it feel canonical like the package was imported, e.g.

`import {foo} from 'package-1'`

But I'm not sure how to bundle up package one as part of my overall build? Help! Can't find much guidance on this.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you are looking for [NPM Workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces)